# Remove Function From WP Parent Theme

Tags: wordpress

In the parent theme's folder there is a function:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'znn_load_js');
function znn_load_js() { 
     include(get_template_directory() . '/javascript.php');
}
```

I want to override it and include my own javascript.php file. I already tried

```
remove_action('wp_footer', 'znn_load_js');
```

But it's not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need this code to be deleted from your theme, I would suggest removing it from your functions.php entirely. However if you need this to be preserved for some reason, you can set the priority of both the add_action, and remove_action. By setting a lower priority, the action will be executed earlier. By setting a higher priority, the action will be executed later. Whether it is an add_action or remove_action the principal is the same.

I would suggest reading both of these for more info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

**1]** add_action has a default priority of 10, but you can manually set it with the 3rd parameter like so:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'znn_load_js', 10);
function znn_load_js() { 
     include(get_template_directory() . '/javascript.php');
}
```

**2]** So set the priority of remove_action and add_action to the same number, in this case, 10. However you could change them both to any priority you want. Place this action hook in the child theme.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_functions');
function remove_parent_functions() {
    remove_action('wp_footer', 'znn_load_js', 10);
}
```

Comment: I need it to be preserved because I'm working on a child theme and I don't want to hack the parent theme's functions.php. The add_action is included in the parent functions file, and the remove_action is included in the child functions file. I set the remove_action priority higher than the parent's but to no resolve. The function.php is still being included.

Comment: Are you able to make any edits to the Parent theme? Or do you have to strictly override the parent theme without changing the parent's functions.php?

Comment: I can make changes to the parent theme if it's necessary, although I would prefer not to simply for the sake of good practice.

Comment: Updated my answer, try setting the priorities to the same number.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try adding an action for after_setup_theme that removes it.